# Performance of font scaling in WinForm TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, font-size

My winform `Form` has a `TextBox` control for which I've implemented Ctrl + MouseWheel zooming and it works like a charm.

I've noticed however, that from a certain font size on up, the font scaling takes up increasing amounts of time to complete/render.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and if there's any way to avoid this (apart from limiting the maximum zoom factor)?

I doubt it's relevant, but I'll include my code in the event that I'm causing this.

```
void xmlForm_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
    {
        if (((Form)sender).Controls[0].Font.Size + (e.Delta / 120) > 1 && ((Form)sender).Controls[0].Font.Size + (e.Delta / 120) < Single.MaxValue)
        {
            Font newFont = new Font(((Form)sender).Controls[0].Font.FontFamily, ((Form)sender).Controls[0].Font.Size + (e.Delta / 120));
            ((Form)sender).Controls[0].Font = newFont;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: Very vague.  Taking a shot at it: I'm guessing you've got the WordWrap property set to True.  It is an expensive operation and costs more time the more it needs to wrap.

Comment: You sir, made a correct guess. You have my thanks. My apologies for the vague question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning the guess into an answer: you've got the WordWrap property set to True.  Word wrapping is in general a pretty expensive operation, the control needs to start measuring strings to see where a line of text needs to be wrapped.  Something it doesn't have to do when WordWrap is false.

The larger you make the font, the less text fits across the window so the more measurements it needs to make.  That slows it down, it gets noticeable to the eye when you have a lot of text in the control.  Simple things like figuring out where to start painting and how to initialize the vertical scrollbar become complicated.  Also very visible in Notepad, using Format + Word Wrap.  With that turned on, the program goes dead for a while when you load a large .txt file.

Comment: Thank you once again for clarifying this.